# Encontrar valores duplicados em uma tabela Oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Tenha uma tabela em uma base Oracle chamada MENSAGEM. Essa tabela possui alguns campos dentre eles LOCALID e APPLICATIONNAME.

Segue exemplos de valores inseridos na base

```
LOCALID - APPLICATIONNAME
1       - app1
1       - app1
1       - app1
2       - app2
2       - app2
2       - app2
1       - app3
1       - app3
```

Em certos momentos o LOCALID está se repetindo para diferentes APPLICATIONNAME.

Preciso encontrar todos esses valores que possuam diferentes APPLICATIONNAME e LOCALID iguais.

Como fazer uma query em Oracle para tal cenário?

Answer (score 1):

Eu não entendi bem qual desses dois você precisaria, então incluí ambos:

Uma consulta para encontrar duplicatas:

```
Select localid, applicationname, count(*)
from mensagem
group by localid, applicationname
having count(*) > 1;
```

Uma consulta para encontrar todas as combinações distintas ou os dois campos.

```
select distinct localid, applicationname 
from mensagem
```